# How to get all fields of a MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In application I write down in a collection of users documents with separate users. Each document is an object in which there is a name of the user and his category. Categories are an object. How can I take all recorded categories. I try to take them through find (), but there I need to specify the key-value. And I just need to specify the category field and take all the key-values ​​there. How can I get all categories of an individual user?
I need to find them by key.

```js
mongoClient.connect(function (err, client) {
  const db = client.db("expensesdb");
  const collection = db.collection("users");

  if (err) return console.log(err);

  collection
    .find({ name: "Bob"})
    .toArray(function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
      client.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: well i didn't get your question very well. But read about mongo aggregation pipeline. That should help to find nested document and perform other operation in a chained manner like first find by name and group all category and then sort by name of category.

Comment: I need to display in the console all categories for a specific user. Categories - this is an object in which the category and price are located. I need to output to the console the entire object of a specific user. In my example, I display all the fields of a user named Bob. And I need to display only the categories

Comment: Try this: `.find({user: "Bob"}, {categories: 1, _id: 0})`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Sample data-set**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("63050125848392dcf6f3ebba"), "name" : "max", "category" : { "cat1" : "max1", "cat2" : "max2" } }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("63050132848392dcf6f3ebbb"), "name" : "box", "category" : { "cat1" : "box1", "cat2" : "box2" } }
```

**Try this aggregation pipeline :**

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { "name": "max" } },{$project : {"category":1}}
  ]);

db.users.aggregate([
    { $match: { "category.cat1": "cat1" } },{$project : {"category":1}}
  ]);
```

**Output for both:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("630500ec848392dcf6f3ebb9"), "category" : { "cat1" : "cat1", "cat2" : "cat2" } }
```